# Finding Node of Matching Raw Html in an HtmlAgility HtmlDocument

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I currently have a program that finds and edits HTML files based on finding a tag with a matching id.

I would like to extend it to find a tag that has matching InnerHtml (disregarding capitalization and whitespace)

What is a good way to use Html Agility to do this?  I would like to do it using Html Agility because the rest of the program is using it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I notice there is an HtmlAgilityPack tag... for some reason, I can't tag this (probably lack of rep), but it might be helpful to others if this question was tagged with it. - Cheers, Scott.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough shooting it here but you should be able to do something like this:

```
            HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("YOUR_TAG_SELECTOR");

            if (nodes != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
                {
                    if (node.InnerHtml.ToLower().Trim() == "YOUR_MATCH")
                    {
                        //success routine
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think this should be node.InnerHtml, not node.InnerText :)

Comment: Ahh yes my apologies I read matching text in the original question. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

We've done this using Regular Expressions.
Something like this works for us:

```
private static List<HtmlNode> GetMatchingNodes(string xPath, string pattern, HtmlDocument htmlDocument)
{
    List<HtmlNode> matchingNodes = new List<HtmlNode>();
    foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xPath))
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(node.InnerHtml, pattern))
        {
            matchingNodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
    return matchingNodes;
}
```

Hope this helps. :)